# How to pass a password from javascript to powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

We have a website on which a user has to put in a password. That password must then be passed to a powershell script as a securestring.
We can do it as a string, but then the password shows up in the logging and that is not acceptable.

I have searched, but cannot find how to create a secureString in javascript.

Code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader,
java.io.IOException,
java.io.InputStreamReader"
%>

<%@ page language="java" %>

<%
String psScript=(String)request.getParameter("script"); 
String cmsnameline=(String)request.getParameter("cmsnameline"); 
String password=(String)request.getParameter("password"); 
String[] parts = cmsnameline.split(",");
String cmsname=parts[0];
String user=parts[1]; 
String creds=parts[2]; 
%>

<%
String param = ("O:\\SapMaintenanceBoard\\Remote_execute.ps1 -script_file " + (psScript.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "")) + " -servers " + (cmsname.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "")) + " -npa_user " + (user) + " -credFile "  + (creds)+ " -password "  + (password));

String command = "powershell.exe " + (param); 

 // Executing the command
  Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  // Getting the results
  powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();

-- Do stuf with the results
%>
```

And the PowerShell:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
  [String]$script_file
  ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
  [String]$servers
  ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
  [String]$user
  ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
  [String]$credFile
  ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4)]
  [String]$password
  )
```

And in PowerShell I need to replace `[String]$password` by `[secureString]$password`.

Comment: This site is to help you to do something, not to do the work for you. Show us what you have tried and what problems you encountered and we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, used my phone for the initial question....

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of to do this... both will give you `$password` as a `System.Security.SecureString` object.

Take the string input and `ConvertTo-SecureString` within your script/function:

```
function Get-Password1 {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$password
    )
    $password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    $password
}

Get-Password1 -password "P@55w0rd"
```

Use `ConvertTo-SecureString` when your call your script/function:

```
function Get-Password2 {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [Security.SecureString]$password
    )

    $password
}

Get-Password2 -password (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@55w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will pass this on the a collegue of mine as I am heading off to the Alps this afternoon and will be offline for a week.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Sorry for the long wait..... Busy.
But this solution didn't work. The main problem lies in the fact that when we start a Powershell process from somewhere (java in this case, but cmd also works) we get an event in the windows log. This event also contains all parameters.
Executing your code from a cmd prompt gives the following in the windows log:
HostApplication=powershell Get-Password1 -password (ConvertTo-SecureString P@55w0rd -AsPlainText -Force)